# IntellijIDEA report deprecated features on Gradle build but normal command doesn't

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

When I run the run configuration for Main this is the console output

```
11:24:01 AM: Executing ':Main.main()'...

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE

> Task :Main.main()
Hello world!

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
11:24:03 AM: Execution finished ':Main.main()'.
```

but when I run the command on the CL this is the output.

[image]

Also the output says Gradle 9.0 but I'm using 8.4. The deprecated error only appears when I execute the program run config and not when normally build the project but using either the command or the built-in gradle-tool-window build task.

gradle build:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'hua.dit.nikosgourn'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'

    implementation 'org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt-main:2.3.2'
    implementation 'org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all-main:2.3.2'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'hua.dit.nikosgourn.Main'
        )
    }
}
```

wrapper.properties:
[image]

Comment: Please follow the related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-331796